# Reading from a TCPServer socket intermittently times out

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpserver

I am trying to send a request to a TCPServer I created, read the request, and eventually write it to a file I am creating.   It works some of the time, but times out often.   This then causes the server to hang as I believe it is blocking the server from closing the socket.

All the only examples suggest that I handle this by rescuing the Errno::EAGAIN exception, as well as the EOFError.  Handling the Errno::EAGAIN using IO.select and retry works 75% of the time, but takes a long time, and seems to time out anyways the other 25% of the time.   Below is my code for creating the TCPServer, creating the socket, and handling the request.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', PORT)

while socket_events = select([server], nil, nil)

    puts "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"

    Thread.new(server.accept) do |socket|


        request = socket.gets 
        content_length = socket.readpartial(1024).match(/Content-Length: \d+/).to_s.split(': ')
        content_length = content_length[1].to_i   
        puts content_length

        @content_file = File.new("#{PATH}/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", "w") 
        @buffer = []
        begin
          @buffer << socket.read_nonblock(content_length)
          puts "buffer is #{@buffer}"
        rescue  Errno::EAGAIN => e
          puts "#{e.message}"
          puts "#{e.backtrace}"
          IO.select([socket])
          retry
        rescue EOFError
          $STDOUT.puts "-" * 50
          puts "request data is #{@buffer}"    
          $STDOUT.puts "-" * 50
          break  
        end

        response = "" #@content_file.path
        headers = ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "server: ruby", "Content-Type: text/plain", "Content-Length: #{response.bytesize}\r\n\r\n"].join("\r\n")

        socket.print headers

        socket.print response  



        @content_file.close
        socket.close


  end

end
```

Comment: my version of ruby is 2.1

Comment: So I moved printing the response back to the client to before the code where I try to read the sockets contents, this allowed the client to receive a reply and not timeout.  However, looks like i am still not reading the request correctly.  Will continue...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the timeout had to do with the client waiting around for the response which had nothing to do with reading the socket..